# Golang: Zip Package Modified Time Defaults to 30 November 1979, 00:00

Tags: go

How do you change the modified time for a zip file to time.Now()? When I create a zip file I get a modified time of 30 November 1979, 00:00.

So is there an easy way to set the modified time to now?

Comment: You need to use https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader.ModTime Or file header. What's the code that you are using?

Comment: @khrm: So you basically create a FileHeader and populate it with the values you want and then pass it to CreateHeader? I wondering if there is a way to copy over the values(besides copying one element at a time) from the file being zipped to the FileHeader variable...

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for, I the zip package they include a function func FileInfoHeader(fi os.FileInfo) (*FileHeader, error) which does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found this function which does what I was looking for: func FileInfoHeader(fi os.FileInfo) (*FileHeader, error). This will take an input data file and create a partially filled FileHeader.

Answer (score 0):

I can now use the input file's os.FileInfo for the FileHeader but the compression ratio is almost 1:1...Meaning its hardly compressing the file now. If I don't use CreateHeader then I get a good compression ratio. Does anyone know why? Here's the code I tried..

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Zip Program!\n\n")

    zbuf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    fmt.Print("Enter input filename: ")
    var ifilename string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &ifilename)

    if ifd, err := os.Open(ifilename); err == nil {
        ibuf := make([]byte, 128)
        zwtr := zip.NewWriter(zbuf)
        fi, _ := ifd.Stat()              //call stat() to get os.FileInfo
        fih, _ := zip.FileInfoHeader(fi) //get FileHeader from input file

        if zw, err := zwtr.CreateHeader(fih); err == nil { //use input file header
            for true {
                if ird, err := ifd.Read(ibuf); err == nil {
                    //fmt.Printf("%s", ibuf[:ird])
                    zw.Write(ibuf[:ird])
                } else {
                    ifd.Close()
                    zwtr.Close()
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("Buf size: %d\n", len(zbuf.Bytes()))

    fmt.Print("Enter zip filename: ")
    var zfilename string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &zfilename)

    if !strings.HasSuffix(zfilename, ".zip") {
        zfilename += ".zip"
    }

    if zfd, err := os.Create(zfilename); err == nil {
        if _, err := zfd.Write(zbuf.Bytes()); err == nil {

        } else {
            fmt.Print(err.Error())
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: Been a while, but just in case someone else ends up here with this problem. The zip.FileHeader structure returned by zip.FileInfoHeader has the Method field initialized to Store, the default, which doesn't compress. If you want compression you need to do:
fih.Method = zip.Deflate
after getting the header from FileInfoHeader